# Did I plagiarized by using a couple of lines from another answer?

Tags: support, plagiarism

I [answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915427/setting-proxy-in-leanft-browserfactory-launch-command/48921271#48921271) question and, in the process, to give a (relative) complete answer, I wanted to also suggest a way to start a process in C#, but was not sure of the exact lines, so I googled it and reached [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181857/3233388) that had the statements needed to start a process in C#.

I copied the only snippet relevant to my answer but I'm not sure if I should've referred the guy who gave the answer or, since it's possibly very common to write those two statements, it's not considered plagiarism.

Can you please shed some light?

Comment: It is not plagiarism if there is only one way to do it.  Everybody would write the same snippet, whether they typed from memory, peeked at the MSDN article or used Google.  But sure, pretty easy to feel better about it by attributing correctly.  Tends to be useful to future readers as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plagiarism is copying someone else's work *without attribution*.  If you provide a clear [attribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attribution) (e.g. a link to the source) then it is clearly not plagiarism.  It is easy to provide some kind of attribution, so you should just do it.

The other point is that copying a couple of sentences and using them as part of a substantially larger answer is technically plagiarism, but would *probably* be *forgiven*.   By most people.  (But why take the risk of offending someone ...)

---

Another alternative to attribution is to use a stylistic convention to indicate that you are quoting someone else's words; e.g.

> "To be or not to be.  That is the question."

At least I am making it clear that those words are not my own<sup>1</sup>.   Now, I would be marked down in an English Lit paper for doing that.  But not for plagiarism.

---

<sup>1 - And nobody is likely to be offended by me not mentioning William Shakespeare as the author ...</sup>

Comment: I understand that *but* I only used 2 lines of code, 1 of them was added by someone else (you can see in the revision history), so what I didn't understand is if taking one line from the author, specifically `Process.Start`, is it **required** to provide attribution. Now I understand that we *should* provide in this case, but not mandatory

Comment: Plagiarism is plagiarism, even one line.   Obviously, for a small enough number of words, it impossible to know if I copied someone's words or not.  But even so, if I did copy the words and pretended they were my own, it would still be plagiarism.